# Why does my submit form take me to my php page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

(I didn't realize that the post I had already made before this could be edited and reopened. Confused about the process...)

When I click to send the form, the email is sent correctly but then I get sent to my php page showing the number 0. I don't get why this is happening. Here's the (mostly)full code:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="js/formCheck.php">
    <div class="formCol">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="formEmail" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your email address..." required/>
    </div>
    <div class="formCol midCol">
        <label id="floatMsg">Message (350 chars):</label>
        <textarea id="formMessage" name="message" rows="5" cols="40" maxlength="350" placeholder="What have you got to say?" required></textarea>

    </div>
    <div class="formCol lastCol">
        <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" name="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
</form>
```

... scripts

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').ajaxForm(function() {
            alert("Thank you for your comment! I will receive it shortly and get back to you as soon as possible.");
            document.getElementById("form").reset();
        });

    });
</script>
```

SEND EMAIL (PHP)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);



    /* Sending Email */
    $from_add = "Visitor";
    $to_add = "user@email.com";
    $subject = "The_Message_Subject";
    $message = "
        Message Information
        Email = $email
        Message = $comment";

    $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";

    mail($to_add, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: on your form `action="js/formCheck.php"` that's php right?

Comment: document.getElementById("form") there is no 'form' id declared in you element.

Comment: edit original question, don't ask twice.

Answer (score 4):

Add `return false` after form reset. Also form id is `contactForm` not just `form`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contactForm').ajaxForm(function() {
            alert("Thank you for your comment! I will receive it shortly and get back to you as soon as possible.");
            document.getElementById("form").reset();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I still have the issue, even with changing to the correct form ID.